# is using too many fragment slowdown an android apps?

Tags: android, android-fragments

My apps need to use almost hundred fragment. Till now i have designed 15 fragment layout and write the java code for corresponding fragment. I am using one button (Called as next button) in each fragment and i wrote the fragment transition code inside the listening event of this button. The problem that i am facing is when i run my apps, it works fine until 8th fragment is transited and then it gradually slowdown the UI response. When i reach 14th fragment, i have to wait almost 2 min to transit from 13th fragment to 14th fragment. The layout xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
android:id="@+id/mc">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Marks:"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
    android:text="participatent question:"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:text="total question:"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginEnd="157dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="157dp"
    android:text="current question:"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_color"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="what is the minimum age to get the driving license ?"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView3">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_color"
        android:text="16 years" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_color"
        android:text="18 years"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_color"
        android:text="21 years"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_color"
        android:text="19 years"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="142dp"
    android:text="next"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtParticipatent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginEnd="86dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="86dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="111"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:text="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMarks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:text="0" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code inside the next button is:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
//FragmentTransaction
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fourteenqsn fq = new fourteenqsn();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.thirteenqsn, fq);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("score",marks);
args.putInt("parti",participatent);
fq.setArguments(args);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

i need to use this same layout inside hundred fragment but text will be different. And also the code inside next button will be same but fragment transition will be different i.e let's say from fragment A to fragment B, fragment B to fragment C and so on. So, how can i solve this problem? how can i optimize my apps so that my apps works fine.

Comment: if layout is same only text is different you can try using a [viewpager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager) or *Horizontal RecyclerView*

Comment: if the layout is the same, why don't you just change the text in views instead of showing another fragment?

Comment: @kId that would be the best option but i have to change the all code :(

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko how can i do? can you please show me an example?

Comment: when you need to load another data - use `yourTextView.setText(yourData.getSomething())` - this way you will set new data to your only one layout

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions :

1.

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
if(fragment != null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```

2.Otherwise check your memory usage too to make sure that your UI isn't taking all your memory.

Sounds like a memory issue.

You can also check memory like this in adb: `adb shell dumpsys meminfo system`

3.Use android profiler to monitory memory too

4.Force garbage collection periodically may sort out the issue.: `System.gc()`

Comment: i am doing the way you assist and i will inform you what will be the result of this :)

Comment: sounds like a memory problem

Comment: Thank you so much i will try all four answer and let you know about the update :) really appreciate :)